# Jboss error while deploying an Arquillian test because of logging.properties

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, jboss-arquillian

When trying to deploy an Arquillian test with maven, I get the following error message

Part from the Surefire-report:

```
Test set: de.shop.bestellverwaltung.domain.ArtikelTest
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed:
104.813 sec <<< FAILURE! de.shop.bestellverwaltung.domain.ArtikelTest  Time elapsed: 104.812 sec  <<< ERROR! org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException: Could not deploy to container: {"JBAS014671: Fehlgeschlagene Dienste"
=> {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"shop.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"shop.war\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"shop.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011555: Failed to configure logging using 'logging.properties' configuration file.
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: className is null"}}      
...
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: {"JBAS014671: Fehlgeschlagene Dienste"
=> {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"shop.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"shop.war\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"shop.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011555: Failed to configure logging using 'logging.properties' configuration file.
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: className is null"}}     
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.getActionResult(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:134)   
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.getResultFromNode(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:123)     
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.get(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:85)    
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.get(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:42)    
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.executeDeploymentPlan(ArchiveDeployer.java:91)     
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deploy(ArchiveDeployer.java:58)    ... 94 more
```

Here the Logging.properties file

```
# Siehe %JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\logging.properties

############################################################
# Globale Properties
############################################################

# Konsole und Log-Datei handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, java.util.logging.FileHandler

# Globaler Log-Level .level= INFO

############################################################
# LogHandler
############################################################

# Logdatei java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = target/junit-%g.log java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 5000000 java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 3 java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter java.util.logging.FileHandler.encoding = ISO-8859-1

# Konsole java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

# [<date/time>] <level> <source> <method>: <log message> java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format = [%1$tc] %2$s %4$s : %5$s%n

############################################################
# Einzelne Log-Level
############################################################

de.shop.level = FINEST
```

I don't understand what "className is null" means in this context or how to locate the error further.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss AS 7 uses JBoss Log Manager for the log manager. It expects more of a log4j style properties configuration than the JDK style.

It doesn't look like you're configuring any handlers, but they are configured differently then what you have commented out FWIW.

I'm assuming the above logging.properties file is in your deployment. If so it should look like:

```
loggers=de.shop
de.shop.level=TRACE
```